# Http Authentication Server Library

Tags: java, http, authentication, spring-security, shiro

Is there any Java library to verify a Basic or Digest Http authentication? Spring Security provides both but Apache Shiro only have Basic.

Is there any library (other than copy-paste classes from Spring) to help implement this?

Thanks.